# how to wait for all ajax calls to be done before testing with jasmine

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jasmine

I would like to wait before all remote files are loaded before I start testing my jasmine (because I don't want to handle `waitsFor`, `spyes` everywhere in my specfile, but only in the start of the file)

`loadDoc` is a function I created to load my remote files

```
loadDoc = function(path, callBack, noDocx) {
var xhrDoc;

if (noDocx == null) {
  noDocx = false;
}
xhrDoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
docxCallback[path] = callBack;
xhrDoc.open('GET', "../examples/" + path, true);
if (xhrDoc.overrideMimeType) {
  xhrDoc.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
}
xhrDoc.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    window.docXData[path] = this.response;
    if (noDocx === false) {
      window.docX[path] = new DocxGen(this.response);
    }
    return docxCallback[path]();
  }
};
return xhrDoc.send();
};
```

test:

```
describe("DocxGen", function() {
var globalcallBack;
globalcallBack = jasmine.createSpy();
loadDoc('imageExample.docx', globalcallBack);
loadDoc('image.png', globalcallBack, true);
....
waitsFor(function() {
  return globalcallBack.callCount >= 10;
});



describe(...)
....
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used synchronous Ajax Requests, so that the code execution of the Jasmine Block only starts after all the documents are loaded.

Here's my code at the beginning of the file (I assume that you want to store the files inside an array named `fileLoaded`.

```
window.fileLoaded=[]

DocUtils.loadDoc= function(path)
{
    xhrDoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrDoc.open('GET', path, false); //This line makes the call asynchronous (the false)
    xhrDoc.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    window.fileLoaded[path]=this.response;
                } 
                else {
                    console.log('error loading doc');
                    if (callback != null) {
                    return callback(true);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    xhrDoc.send();
}

DocUtils.loadDoc('tagExampleExpected.docx')
DocUtils.loadDoc('tagLoopExample.docx')
DocUtils.loadDoc('tagLoopExampleImageExpected.docx')
DocUtils.loadDoc('tagProduitLoop.docx')
```